# Can't use ^ to say "all but"

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text in which I want to get only the hexadecimal codes.
Like: "thisissometextthisistext\x64\x6f\x6e\x74\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x6c\x61\x74\x65somemoretextoverhere"

It's possible to get the hex codes with **\x..**
But it doesn't seems I can do something like **(^\x..)** to select everything **but** the hex codes.

Any workarounds?

Comment: Try `(?s)((?:\\x[a-fA-F0-9]{2})+)|.` regex and `(?1$1\n:)` replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `(?s)((?:\\x[a-fA-F0-9]{2})+)|.` regex (that will match and capture into Group 1 any 1+ sequences of hex values OR will just match any other char including a line break char) and replace with a conditional replacement pattern `(?{1}$1\n:)` (that will reinsert the hex value chain or will replace the match with an empty string):

**Find What**:      `(?s)((?:\\x[a-fA-F0-9]{2})+)|.`
**Replace With**: `(?{1}$1\n:)`

[image]

**Regex Details**:

- `(?s)`  - same as *`.`  matches newline* option ON
- `((?:\\x[a-fA-F0-9]{2})+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more sequences of

  - `\\x` - a `\\x`
  - `[a-fA-F0-9]{2}`  - 2 letters from `a`  to `f` or digits
- `|` - or
- `.` - any single char.

**Replacement pattern**:

- `(?{1}`  - if Group 1 matches:

  - `$1\n` - replace with its contents + a newline
  - `:` - else replace with an empty string
- `)` -  end of the replacement pattern.

Comment: Thanks it worked well, i just used **\1** to replace instead

Comment: In Notepad++, `\1` is equal to `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

try `^.*?((\\x[a-f0-9]{2})+).*$`   and replace with `$1`

and it should just leave the hex code

[image]

then after replace

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are already able to find the hexcodes with your regex, couldn't you just use that information to delete all of the hexcodes from the string (or from a clone of the string if you need to preserve the original) and you would be left with all text except for hexcodes.

Comment: he wants the hex codes and to get rid of the other stuff

Answer (score 0):

`^` acts as a negation token only inside (and at the beginning) of a character class, you can't use it to negate substrings of several characters.

To select all that isn't `\xhh` you can use this pattern:

```
\G(?:\\x[a-f0-9]{2})*+\K(?=.|\n)[^\\]*(?:\\(?!x[a-f0-9]{2})[^\\]*)*
```

it matches the `\xhh`s first and removes them from the match using the `\K` feature (that removes all on the left). The other part of the pattern `[^\\]*(?:\\(?!x[a-f0-9]{2})[^\\]*)*` matches all that isn't a `\xhh`. Since this subpattern can match the empty string at the end of the string, I added the lookahead `(?=.|\n)` to ensure there's at least one character.
`\G` forces all matches to be contigous. In other words it matches the position at the end of the previous match.